# How to make all my site scripts safe for browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, unsafe, google-webfonts

Okay, so i have this problem, i tried searching it on google, had no luck.
When a browser loads my site, it says that there are unsafe scripts there, but all the scripts are working properly except google fonts. To make them work i have to click "load all scripts anyways". Is it possible to make that browsers wouldn't recognise my scripts and google fonts as unsafe? i'm hosting my site on a dropbox.

Comment: I wonder if hosting your site on dropbox is the problem.

Comment: Pretty sure that's the problem. By chance, do you have any scripts with `https://` in their address while your "site" is accessed over `http://`, or vice versa?

Comment: thanks, i'll try to host somewhere else. I have jquerry file in the same directory linked withouth https:// and all scripts are in <script> tags @JLRishe

Comment: What's the URL of the Google fonts script? That's the one that sounds like it has a problem.

Comment: @Jockey Can you provide a screenshot of the "unsafe scripts" dialog? Also, please share what the origins of your page and your scripts look like (e.g., "my page is on `https://dropboxcontent.com/foo...` and my scripts are `http://google.com/.../bar.js` and `https://dropboxcontent.com/.../qux.js`")? No need to share the share the whole URL, but scheme and domain would be nice.

Comment: Dropbox was the problem, changed to github, now everything works just fine